# Deleted WebService in Visual Studio is still invoked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I'm using javascript + webservice methods in an asp.net/vb.net project.

I've created the WebService like this: in the project solution i did "add" -> "new item" -> "web service".

With the configuration of the webservice working, I created a "WebService1.asmx", then tried to run one method, and everything worked.

After this, I deleted "WebService1.asx" and created a new one called "MyWebService.asmx". I updated the service reference, but the project don't see this new file.

So I then deleted "MyWebService.asmx" and created a new "WebService1.asmx" but with a different method than before.

Now the project sees the file, but I don't understand why it is still the old method of "WebService1.asx" running.

Code. The references:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService1.asmx" />
        </Services>

...
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The WebService:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel


<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _

Public Class WebService1
  Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

  <WebMethod()> _
  Public Function HelloWorld() As String
       Return "Hello World"
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Try to build the solution

Comment: @pankysharma still doesn't work!!

Comment: try to clean and rebuild the solution, also set the reference to a fake path like webservice100.asmx, then rebuild then set path correct and rebuild.
It will be set by then

Comment: Well, i've added "system.web" to the web service imports.
I've to rebuild every time the site master and if i change the method i've to rewrite always the entire namespace in the call.

now working